# I need a regex to validate a Jordanian number with or with out the country code

Tags: javascript, html

I need the regex to validate all numbers that start with 0096279 0096278 0096277 and 079 078 077.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: ^(009627|9627|\+9627|07|7)(|9|8|7)([0-9]{7})$ I have tried this regex but its not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Good tool for testing regex is [this online tool](https://regex101.com/)

I tested this regex and this collect all numbers that starts and ends with your numbers:

```
^(0096279|0096278|0096277)(.*?)(079|078|077)$
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: can you post some code that you are useing

Comment: sorry, i had `111` test numbers in regex, i edited the post now.

Comment: I am sorry I know nothing about codes, I only needed a ready regex for something in my work. I can't seem to find it anywhere though!! ^(0096279|0096278|0096277)(.*?)(079|078|077)$
I tried this also and it still wont work.